# Autofac: No scope with a Tag matching AutofacWebRequest

Tags: entity-framework, injeção-de-dependência

gostaria da ajuda de vocês para resolver o seguinte problema:
Imaginem que tenho uma classe ServiceFactory responsavel por criar serviços (como `srvFact.Create<MyService>()`), uma classe RepositoryFactory responsável pela criação de repositórios (como `repFact.Create<MeuRepositorio>()`). Tais classes possuem dependências, que demontrarei através do simbolo `A <= B`, que denota que A depende de B. Para o meu caso tenho que:
`ServiceFactory <= RepositoryFactory`.
`RepositoryFactory  <= DbContext`.
Dito isso, imaginem que minha api utiliza o Automapper para mapear ViewModels em Objetos do Entity Framework e que para certos mapeamentos, se faz necessário acessar algum repositório.
O que eu quero: Gostaria que dado um request, enquanto esse request viver, qualquer requisição a uma instância de DbContext, retorne a mesma instância, para controlar melhor o ciclo de vidade do DbContext. Vamos ao trecho de codigo:

```c
internal void Configure(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    ConfigureContainer(builder);
    Container = builder.Build();
    RegisterMapping();
}

private void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    var dbContextType = GetDbContextType();
    var assembly = GetWebApiAssembly();

    // (a) com essa linha o metodo 'RegisterMapping' não consegue resolver a instancia de ServiceFactory
    builder.RegisterType(dbContextType).As(typeof(DbContext)).InstancePerRequest();

    // (b) COM ESSA LINHA, O METODO 'RegisterMapping' consegue obter uma instancia de ServiceFactory
    //builder.RegisterType(dbContextType).As(typeof(DbContext)).InstancePerRequest("myrequest");

    builder.RegisterType<RepositoryFactory>().As<IRepositoryFactory>();
    builder.RegisterType<ServiceFactory>().As<IServiceFactory>();
    builder.RegisterApiControllers(assembly);
}

private void RegisterMapping()
{
    // usando (a) no metodo 'ConfigureContainer' temos um erro:
    // 'No scope with a Tag matching AutofacWebRequest'
    var serviceFactory = Container.Resolve<IServiceFactory>();
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => ConfigureMapping(cfg, serviceFactory));

    // usando (b) no metodo 'ConfigureContainer' conseguimos resolver ServiceFactory, porém é injetado instancias diferentes de DbContext
    // o que faz com que o mapeamento dentro de 'ConfigureMapping' gere o erro: 
    // 'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker'
    //using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope("myrequest"))
    //{
    //    var serviceFactory = scope.Resolve<IServiceFactory>();
    //    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => ConfigureMapping(cfg, serviceFactory));
    //}
}
```

O Método `Configure(new ContainerBuilder())` é chamado no Global.asax: `DbAccessWrapper.Init(new VaiQueConfig());` onde o construtor `new VaiQueConfig()` chama o método `Configure` passando uma instancia de `ContainerBuilder`

Comment: desculpe.. não consegui entender o que deseja e qual o seu problema. está dando algum erro? ou deseja "melhorar" a forma como `utiliza injeção de dependência`?

Comment: Estou tendo problemas, o primeiro é que `var serviceFactory = scope.Resolve<IServiceFactory>()` gera um erro (No scope with a Tag matching AutofacWebRequest
) se configuro o container com a linha `builder.RegisterType(dbContextType).As(typeof(DbContext)).InstancePerRequest()`;

Comment: O segundo é que, se utilizo a linha `builder.RegisterType(dbContextType).As(typeof(DbContext)).InstancePerRequest("myrequest")` eu consigo obter a instancia de ServiceFactory, mas a dependencia (RepositoryFactory) injetada em ServiceFactory  é injetada com uma nova instancia do DbContext, ja que RepositoryFactory tem como dependencia DbContext, e isso gera o erro (An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker) ao utilizar o servico na camada de mapeamento

Comment: Por favor, alguem?

Comment: Difícil esse seu caso, como não sei o que é, vou comentar.. se der certo respondo, você já tentou fazer assim `builder.RegisterType<SeuDbContext>().As<DbContext>();` para injetar o contexto?

Comment: ja sim, vou postar o link do repositorio, caso queira simular para entender. no geral quero construir um plugin que faz crud generico, ja mapeando viewmodels em dto, mas para isso, preciso de uma instancia apenas do contexto entity por request para evitar erros de multiplos contextos, ou erros quando mult thread quando o contexto é singleton Repositório: https://github.com/Jass91/WebApiLink

Comment: Desculpe, na verdade nao posso usar como vc falou, pois preciso obter dinamicamente o tipo da classe que herda de DbContext, pois cada pessoa poderia ter um. ex: MeuDbCtx1, ODbCtxDele e etc...